# How can I view rtsp playbacks continuously?

Tags: rtsp, playback

I have an application on which I can view RTSP live streams with the help of [RTSPtoWeb](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWeb) application.

I also want to view playbacks from RTSP when user searches for a time range. However, to the best of my knowledge, to make it with RTSPtoWeb I have to save the rtsp request for the time range and then call it from my app.

My video source keeps playbacks in 5 minutes of ranges. In this case I need to save 12 different rtsp streams to RTSPtoWeb and then stream them one after another.

Is there another approach I can stream playbacks without creating new stream instances on RTSPtoWeb for each search request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [RTSPtoWeb](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWeb) as a middle layer and sent the request **without endtime parameter**. It continued to stream even after the file finished.

For example for my hikvision dvr I added the stream to RTSPtoWeb with this format:

> rtsp://[user]:[password]@[host]/Streaming/tracks/[channel/?starttime=20221228T174200Z

my earlier request was like this (where the end time was the end of the stored record file in nvr system):

> rtsp://[user]:[password]@[host]/Streaming/tracks/[channel/?starttime=20221228T174200Z&endtime=20221228T174602Z